# Agent limit in Puppet opensource

Tags: puppet

Is there any agent limit in Puppet opensource version?
One of my colleagues suggested to double check. 
I did notice a 10 agent limit in evaluation version of enterprise version. Couldn't find any such info about puppet open-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no agent limits on open source Puppet.

For large number of nodes you might need multiple Masters but that is possible with the open source version as well as Puppet Enterprise.

Largest difference is that the enterprise version provides more addional features and support while core Puppet is the same on both versions.

More about it on: https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-enterprise